# Automatic save html input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have input:

```
<input type="text" name="rename" id="rename" value="test">
```

If I edit this input, I need to click to another place to save it, but how I can save it automatically?

Does Jquery/js have a function to save inputs?

Comment: Ajaaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: As Suresh pointed out you could use AJAX call to server to save values and you could call Ajax call inside change event on element you wish to save.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and describe what is not working. Yes you can use a library such as JQuery. What you are looking for is AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) event

```
$("#rename").on("input", function() {
  // do stuff
})
```